# Idiomatic way to unpack result/option of tuple into a tuple of result/option in rust

Tags: rust

Sometimes we may have multiple values in form of a tuple, but wrapped in `Result` (or `Option`), because they all either exist together or not at all, for example `Result<(i32, &str), _>`. But then it might be necessary to process them completely separately, so it could be beneficial to have `Result<i32, _>` and `Result<&str, _>` separately.

What I do in this situation is usually:

```
let pair: Result<_, String> = Ok((10, "x"));
let (a, b) = match pair {
    Ok((a, b)) => (Ok(a), Ok(b)),
    Err(e) => (Err(e.clone()), Err(e)),
};
```

(or slightly simpler for `Option`, because there's no need to clone error).

But this seems a bit cumbersome.

Alternatively, both `a` and `b` could be mapped from the original `pair`, like so:

```
let a = pair.clone().map(|(a, _)| a);
let b = pair.map(|(_, b)| b);
```

But this clones not only the error part, but also the values, even though it is not necessary. Another alternative would be to use `as_ref` instead of `clone` if having references in `a` and `b` is ok.

Now the question is, is there anything more idiomatic than this? Ideally, I would like to have something like:

```
fn split<T, U, E: Clone>(x: Result<(T, U), E>) -> (Result<T, E>, Result<U, E>) {
    match x {
        Ok((a, b)) => (Ok(a), Ok(b)),
        Err(e) => (Err(e.clone()), Err(e)),
    }
}
```

but preferably generic over the length of the tuple, but couldn't find anything similar in the standard library.

Comment: The fact that you have a `Result<(T, U)>` means you almost certainly _should_ be handling it as one Result/Error; when you split it into `Result<T>` and `Result<U>`, you no longer express the fact that they're either both `Ok` or both `Err`. If you need to split the tuple, you should do inside something like `res.map(|(a, b)| (handle_T(a), handle_U(b)))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Option` there is [`Option::unzip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unzip) to do that, for `Result` there isn't such combinator. You can propose adding it, if you think it's useful.

Comment: Good to know there's `unzip`, that covers 50% of my use cases. Thanks!